# How to include OR in Array formula where ONLY SOME criteria need to be TRUE - Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, count

I am trying to count the number of rows that: 1) have entries for all columns, and ii) have at least one value that meets a column-specific criterion.

Here's an example:

```
A B C D
4 4 3 5
2 2 2 2
3 1 2 5
1   3 2
```

- Column A Threshold: >2
- Column B Threshold: >2
- Column C Threshold: <2
- Column D Threshold: >4

The answer for this example is 2 because 2/4 rows include at least 1 value that meets a column threshold. Specifically, row 1 has 3 values that meet the column thresholds and Row 3 has 2 values. Row 2 has no values that meet the column-threshold, while row 4 should not be counted because it does not contain entries for all columns, e.g.:

```
A B C D
T T F T
F F F F
T F F T
F F F F
```

So I don't want to count how many times a specific column threshold has been met in each row, but whether at least 1 has been met in each row.

I have a hunch that SUMPRODUCT could be useful for this issue, but I do not know how to add an OR criterion for only some criteria (for instance, the example [described here](https://superuser.com/questions/97244/how-do-you-include-an-or-inside-a-sumproduct-function-in-microsoft-excel) of using a "+" in SUMPRODUCTS as an OR function counts both the criteria).

Your thoughts would be most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very interesting question.

**Array formula**:**

`=SUM(N(MMULT(IF(MMULT(N(A1:D4=""),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:D4)^0))=0,COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:D4)-MIN(ROW(A1:D4)),COLUMN(A1:D4)-MIN(COLUMN(A1:D4))),{">2",">2","<2",">4"}),0),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:D4)^0))>0))`

***Edit**: Without the presence of blanks within the range, this could be simplified greatly to:*

`=ROWS(A1:D4)-COUNTIFS(A1:A4,"<=2",B1:B4,"<=2",C1:C4,">=2",D1:D4,"<=4")`

since, logically, to obtain the number of rows for at which **at least one** condition is true, we can calculate the number of rows for which **none of those** conditions are true and subtract that value from the total number of rows.

In fact, it may well be possible to adapt this set-up to account for blanks as well. Will look into it.

**Update:** Indeed, I believe this will work:

`=ROWS(A1:D4)-COUNTIFS(A1:A4,"<=2",B1:B4,"<=2",C1:C4,">=2",D1:D4,"<=4")-COUNT(1/N(MMULT(N(A1:D4=""),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:D4)^0))>0))`

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Lovely solution.

Comment: @MichalRosa Thanks! Though not sure I'm not missing something simpler. Quite unusual to have to compare a 2D range against criteria with different comparison operators. If the operator were the same for each column, e.g. all ">", then the solution would be straightforward.

Comment: I started working on it and eventually find a different solution but it was really convoluted.  Fortunately you've answered the question before I could post it!  I’ll add your formula to my library. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you both for your input. @XORLX "Quite unusual to have to compare a 2D range against criteria with different comparison operators". Precisely - it's had be stumped for a while now! Your solution is so elegant.

Comment: @PyjamaNinja Thanks, though I've just updated the post having noticed a logical 'shortcut' which I may be able to make work for the case where blanks are present also. Now that really would be elegant!

Comment: @PyjamaNinja Just noticed that the original formula I posted wasn't sound in that it didn't always cope with blanks within the range. Have updated.

Comment: @PyjamaNinja Simpler version now updated to account for blanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for pushing the envelope with this. I will test it now and let you know how it functions!

Comment: I tested both the original and updated formulae and didn't have any problems. The only issue I noticed is that Excel would throw a circularity error if one edited the data matrix and auto-updated the formula. So perhaps these are end-product formulae? It's not an issue in the current case, but just for others to know. @XORLX I have posted a new question with a slightly updated problem, if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484858/indexing-non-sequential-arrays-in-an-array-formula-excel

Answer (score 2):

Can I offer as a kind of lemma to @XOR LX's brilliant answer that you might be able to do this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A4,"<>",B1:B4,"<>",C1:C4,"<>",D1:D4,"<>")-COUNTIFS(A1:A4,"<=2",B1:B4,"<=2",C1:C4,">=2",D1:D4,"<=4")
```

i.e. The number of rows not containing a blank minus the number of these which don't fulfil any of the conditions.

Comment: This answer certainly deserves credit - why don't you add it to the question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484858/indexing-non-sequential-arrays-in-an-array-formula-excel
It seems to fit the bill

Comment: My answer pales into overcomplication in light of this!

Comment: I would never have thought of it without seeing yours first though