# Excel - Count The Occurrence of One Pair of Values Across Multiple Columns

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, count, countif

I have a matrix:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
67  1   43  48  49  49
12          35  50  50
            33      
22  33              33
```

I want to count the number of rows that have entries for at least one pair of pre-specified columns. It is simply a matter of whether the cell has a value or not (rather than a specific value). The column pairings are A-D, B-E, and C-F.

In the current example, the answer is 2 because 2 rows - rows 1 and 2 - contain entries for at least one pair of columns. Specifically, row 1 has entries for all column pairs, while row 2 contains entries for the A-D column pair - but this alone suffices the criterion. If row 4 had an entry in column E then this too would meet the criterion and the answer would change to 3).

I have already thought about how to count pairs of entries for two columns using the following array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A4<>"",IF(D1:D4<>"",1,0)))
```

However, I am having difficulty extending this to multiple columns with an `OR` type feature that only counts one pair of entries per row, even if that row contains more pairings.

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471396/how-to-include-or-in-array-formula-where-only-some-criteria-need-to-be-true-ex) which might be useful to look at.

I would appreciate your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think again if it doesn't break down easily into separate sums then a conventional array formula is easiest with * for AND and + for OR (with Sign function being used to condense OR(1,1...) into 1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN((A1:A4<>"")*(D1:D4<>"")+(B1:B4<>"")*(E1:E4<>"")+(C1:C4<>"")*(F1:F4<>"")))
```

Comment: I must admit I did try to attack the problem with SUMPRODUCT [e.g., SUMPRODUCT(--((A1:A4<>"")*(D1:D4<>""))+((B1:B4<>"")*(E1:E4<>""))+((C1:C4<>"")*(F1:F4<>"")))] but of course I am missing what I don't understand - the Sign function. What a creative use of a function!

Comment: You can just use --((...sum of terms...)>0) but I tend to use Sign - just personal preference.

Comment: I guess if you have a lot of column pairs it might also be worth looking at Advanced Filter. I'm not sure if it has a lot of fans, but it is a quick way of setting up and/or conditions without typing a long formula.

Answer (score 2):

It's not pretty, but it appears to work (at least for the sample data provided):

[image]
    =SUM(($A$1:$A$4<>"")*($D$1:$D$4<>""))+SUM(($B$1:$B$4<>"")*
    ($E$1:$E$4<>""))+SUM(($C$1:$C$4<>"")*($F$1:$F$4<>""))-SUM(($A$1:$A$4<>"")* 
    ($D$1:$D$4<>"")*($B$1:$B$4<>"")*($E$1:$E$4<>""))-SUM(($A$1:$A$4<>"")*($D$1:$D$4<>"")* 
    ($C$1:$C$4<>"")*($F$1:$F$4<>""))-SUM(($B$1:$B$4<>"")*($E$1:$E$4<>"")*($C$1:$C$4<>"")* 
    ($F$1:$F$4<>""))+SUM(($A$1:$A$4<>"")*($D$1:$D$4<>"")*($B$1:$B$4<>"")*($E$1:$E$4<>"")* 
    ($C$1:$C$4<>"")*($F$1:$F$4<>""))

Count of rows where A&D have values + count of rows where B&E have values + count of rows where C&F have values - count of rows where A,D,B,E have values - count of rows where A,D,C,F have values - count of rows where B,E,C,F have values + count of rows where all 6 have values.

Comment: Thank you so much for having a stab at this. It turns out this is what I started doing, but I have 20+ column pairs, which makes it both unsightly and overwhelming. This would definitely work with the sample data provided, however.